# Colocar em 1 lista dados de varias coluna da mesma tabela MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Oi. Preciso de uma coisa aparentemente simples, mas não estou conseguindo.
Tenho 2 colunas e preciso listar os registros em 1 só.

Tabela tb_dados

| Coluna1 | Coluna2 |
| --- | --- |
| Joao | São Paulo |
| Maria | Campinas |
| Marcos | Florianopolis |
| Ronaldo | Bahia |

Preciso pegar esses dados e listar em 1 consulta como se fosse 1 coluna só.

SELECT * FROM   tb_dados
Preciso do Resultado assim:

| Coluna resultado |
| --- |
| Joao |
| Maria |
| Marcos |
| Ronaldo |
| São Paulo |
| Campinas |
| Florianopolis |
| Bahia |

agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Não tem muito como fugir de selecionar cada coluna separadamente e juntar os resultados:

```sql
SELECT Coluna1 FROM tb_dados
UNION ALL
SELECT Coluna2 FROM tb_dados
```

Importante ressaltar que isso retornará TODOS os valores de ambas as colunas sem remover qualquer possível duplicidade, bem como irá retornar todos os valores da `Coluna1` primeiro e depois todos da `Coluna2`.

Se precisar qualquer resultado diferente deste, será necessário fazê-la como uma sub consulta e aplicar as condições que deseja sobre o resultado.